# std::tr1::shared_ptr and dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, casting, smart-pointers

I use `shared_ptr` with constructing an object like this:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<RawClusterBase> rawCluster(new RawClusterBase());
// ...
rawCluster->addLabel(p->userFriendlyTerms());
// ...
const TokenizedDocument * tokenizedDoc
   = (TokenizedDocument *)documents.at(i);
const RawDocument * rawDoc
   = dynamic_cast<const RawDocument *>(tokenizedDoc->getProperty(
      TokenizedDocument::_PROPERTY_RAW_DOCUMENT));
rawCluster->addDocument(rawDoc);
```

I get a segmentation fault on the line with the `dynamic_cast`:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b92429 in __dynamic_cast () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7b92429 in __dynamic_cast () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0000000000444aa5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe258) at clustering/document_test.cpp:271
```

Can anybody give me a pointer how to solve that? I have a other section in my project
where I use `dynamic_cast` to analyze subclass. I also plan to use the `shared_ptr` there
but I am afraid I would run into the same troubles. Is `dynamic_cast` not working with `shared_ptr`?

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is tokenizedDoc? How is it initialized ? What does the method invoked return ? And finally, what does the invoked method do ?

Comment: You're not using dynamic cast on a shared pointer, you're using it on tokenizedDoc->getProperty ... post the rest of your code, or better yet, a minimal example.

Comment: Put the returned value of `tokenizedDoc->getProperty(TokenizedDocument::_PROPERTY_RAW_DOCUMENT)` in some temporary variable, and make sure it points on a valid polymorphic object. It probably isn't.

Comment: @Mahesh: Sorry, forgot that line. I just added it. TokenizedDocument is object an taken from a vector and points to a property value.

Comment: @eran: I need to cast that line like that and can not put it in an tmp. variable, because have to cast it from the **base Object** to derived type **RawDocument**. Without that cast I get an compiler error.

Comment: What is the return type of `getProperty`? Are you sure it's returning a valid pointer?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The return type is of **const * Object**, the **RawDocument** object is a derived type of class Object. It returns a valid pointer, because if I construct **RawClusterBase** regular, such as **RawClusterBase * rawCluster = new RawClusterBase()** all works well.

Comment: In which way does this have anything to do with the `shared_ptr`? You don't use the `shared_ptr` together with a `dynamic_cast` in any way here.

Comment: @Christian Rau: I want to use the shared_ptr to use with the construction of RawClusterBase to be free of deallocating of that pointer. If I construct the Object like the regular way (see 2 comments before) I have no problem and all works fine. With the shared_ptr I get a seg flt. So I try to investigate with a little help of you guys what could be the reason. I am new to shared_ptr.

Comment: @AndreasW.Wylach The thing is just that your example code doesn't mix `shared_ptr`s with `dynamic_cast`. The usage of both concepts in your code is completely orthogonal. The only way `shared_ptr` could possibly interfere with the `dynamic_cast` would be if you assign the result of a `dynamic_cast` to a `shared_ptr` or pass a `shared_ptr` to a `dynamic_cast`, but I don't see your code do that, so the `shared_ptr` shouldn't have to do anything with the problem of the `dynamic_cast`. The only possible interference could be if `getProperty` returned a `shred_ptr`, but you say it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what might be going wrong. It could be due to a buffer overrun or access to a deallocated pointer, because such things are likely to overwrite a vtable pointer (which occurs at the beginning of an object). Try running the program in Valgrind.

Typically `dynamic_cast` shouldn't crash. It returns `nullptr` (or throws `std::bad_cast` when using references) if the cast is invalid, or it fails to compile if the cast is totally impossible. But it doesn't invoke UB, so I'd look elsewhere for the culprit.

Comment: I try my best to find the problem somewhere else in my code why it fails .... Maybe in my propertyProvider classes. It is just I see no other problems, even valgrind tells me nothing much if I do not use shared_ptr. But I will further look ...

Comment: Its been a few weeks now but I resolved the issue with some changes in my property provider classes that indeed returned an invalid pointer with an object cloning that was invoked in some other part. I removed that piece of code (because it was redundant anyway), also I did some changes in the cloning method of the property class itself. I assume there was the culprit, because since these changes of code the error is gone and now the dynamic_cast's at the questionable part are working fine!

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't evident from the provided code, but in all likelihood, either:

- `documents.at(i)` doesn't return a valid `TokenizedDocument` pointer
- `tokenizedDoc->getProperty(TokenizedDocument::_PROPERTY_RAW_DOCUMENT)` is returning an invalid pointer.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but without the shared_ptr I can not see any problem and dynamic_cast would fail in that case if there is an invalid ptr. But it doesn't. When I added the shared_ptr, I started to see the seg. flts with the dynamic_cast. I checked the loop for invalid pointers but there is nothing I can see.

Comment: I recommend that you post a complete code example that shows this problem.  There is a bug somewhere, but it involves code that's not shown here.

Comment: It is not possible like that, because then I have to post all involved classes of the objects and he PropertyProvider classes to really reproduce this problem. I will have to do further investigation, maybe there is a flaw in the property provider classes. I can not think of any problem up to now as I tested the Property classes well, but maybe there is a bug that shows up with this construct of code ...

Comment: I have found it to be a good exercise (when a huge pile of code hides a bug somewhere) to copy the project and in that copy start removing components one-by-one and checking if the bug persists.  You will either find the cause of the bug on your own or you'll end up with a small enough program to post here.  Good luck!

Comment: That is a good idea. I will start at the property provider classes as they are in a source sub branch and I can compile them easily "stand-alone" to make some tests. I will start from there. I surely will report back on that, as soon as I found the problem and the solution as it might be helpful to others with a similar issue. I just need a few days since that is a side project but to be finished asap!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use such old-C cast in your C++ code:

```
const TokenizedDocument * tokenizedDoc
    = (TokenizedDocument *)documents.at(i);
```

Looks like your `document.at(i)` returns pointer to something else. Try to remove `(TokenizedDocument *)` completely.